# Rotating a shape in KineticJS seems to move it out of sync with it's group

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am working on some image viewing tools in KineticJS.  I have a rotate tool.  When you move the mouse over an image, a line appears from the centre of the image to the mouse position, and then when you click and move, the line follows and the image rotates around that point, in sync with the line.  This works great.

My issue is, I have the following set up:

Canvas->
Stage->
Layer->
GroupA->
GroupB->
Image

This is because I draw tabs for options on GroupA and regard it as a container for the image.  GroupB is used because I flip GroupB to flip the image ( and down the track, any objects like Text and Paths that I add to the image ), so that it flips but stays in place.  This all works well.  I am also hoping when I offer zoom, to zoom groupb and thus zoom anything drawn on the image, but for groupA to create clipping and continue to support drag buttons, etc.

The object I am rotating, is GroupA.  Here is the method I call to set up rotation:

```
this.init = function(control)
{
    console.log("Initing rotate for : " + control.id());

    RotateTool.isMouseDown = false;
    RotateTool.startRot = isNaN(control.getRotationDeg()) ? 0 : control.getRotationDeg();
    RotateTool.lastAngle = control.parent.rotation() / RotateTool.factor;
    RotateTool.startAngle = control.parent.rotation();

    this.image = control.parent;

    var center = this.getCentrePoint();

    RotateTool.middleX = this.image.getAbsolutePosition().x + center.x;
    RotateTool.middleY = this.image.getAbsolutePosition().y + center.y;

    this.image.x(this.image.x() + center.x - this.image.offsetX());
    this.image.y(this.image.y() + center.y - this.image.offsetY());
    this.image.offsetX(center.x);
    this.image.offsetY(center.y);
}
```

getCentrePoint is a method that uses trig to get the size of the image, based on the rotation.  As I draw a line to the centre of the image, I can tell it's working well, to start with.  I've also stepped in to it and it always returns values only slightly higher than the actual width and height, they always look like they should be about what I'd expect, for the angle of the image.

Here is the code I use on mouse move to rotate the image:

```
this.layerMouseMove = function (evt, layer)
{
    if (RotateTool.isRotating == false)
        return;

    if (!Util.isNull(this.image) && !Util.isNull(this.line))
    {
        if (Item.moving && !RotateTool.isRotating)
        {
            console.log("layer mousemove item moving");

            RotateTool.layerMouseUp(evt, layer);
        }
        else
        {
            var pt = this.translatePoint(evt.x, evt.y);
            var x = pt.x;
            var y = pt.y;

            var end = this.getPoint(x, y, .8);

            RotateTool.line.points([this.middleX, this.middleY, end.x, end.y]);
            RotateTool.line.parent.draw();

            RotateTool.sign.x(x - 20);
            RotateTool.sign.y(y - 20);

            var angle = Util.findAngle({ x: RotateTool.startX, y: RotateTool.startY }, { x: x, y: y }, { x: RotateTool.middleX, y: RotateTool.middleY });

            var newRot = (angle) + RotateTool.startAngle;

            RotateTool.image.rotation(newRot);

            console.log(newRot);
        }
    }
}
```

Much of this code is ephemeral, it's maintaining the line ( which is 80% of the length from the centre to my mouse, as I also show a rotate icon, over the mouse.

Sorry for the long windedness, I'm trying to make sure I am clear, and that it's obvious that I've done a lot of work before asking for help.

So, here is my issue.  After I've rotated a few times, when I click again, the 'centre' point that the line draws to, is way off the bottom right of my screen, and if I set a break point, sure enough, the absolute position of my groups are no longer in sync.  This seems to me like my rotation has moved the image in the manner I hoped, but moved my group off screen.  When I set offsetX and offsetY, do I need to also set it on all the children ? But, it's the bottom child I can see, and the top group I set those things on, so I don't really understand how this is happening.

I do notice my image jumps a few pixels when I move the mouse over it ( which is when the init method is called ) so I feel like perhaps I am just out slightly somewhere, and it's causing this flow on effect.  I've done some more testing, and my image always jumps slightly up and to the right when I move the mouse over it, and the rotate tool continues to work reliably, so long as I don't move the mouse over the image again, causing my init method to call.  It seems like every time this is called, is when it breaks.  So, I could just call it once, but I'd have to associate the data with the image then, for the simple reason that once I have many images, I'll need to change my data as my selected image changes.  Either way, I'd prefer to understand and resolve the issue, than just hide it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have a theory.  I think the issue is to do with the top left position not being what it claims to be, so when I set image.setX(image.getX() + ...., the issue is that the x it gets, does not take in to account the rotation, but the x it sets, does, if that makes sense.  I think I need to translate my x and y points by my rotation.  Still stuck, but that's the line I am pursuing, if anyone has any insight

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Not easily, it's inside a complex lot of code.  I asked this again and it's been solved, I'm working on zooming in to an image with a mouse wheel now :-)